# Firebase find all parents with specific child id

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have the following structure in my database. I know the value of the workouts key and I'm trying to find all exercise_templates where the workouts key match. To be honest I'm not sure this is the best way to structure the database either, I'm looking to do a many-to-many relation between exercise_templates and workouts. I'm using JS.

[image: Firebase DB structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Many to Many Relationship, may I  suggest  this structure ? :

```
Exercise_templates
   "KBIhcF3L6eTOSSsGzmW"
      name: "Squats"
      reps: 5
      sets: 5
      workouts
          "KBIYJv6x1YU98eLIwoC": true
          Etc …..   

    "KBIhfwX45S82zyy-8_r"
       name: "Squats"
       reps: 5
       sets: 5
       workouts
          "KBIdNKOko-ZMY-B04qI": true

workouts
   "KBIYJv6x1YU98eLIwoC"
      templates
         "KBIhcF3L6eTOSSsGzmW" : true
          Etc… 

    "KBIhfwX45S82zyy-8_r"
        templates
        etc…
```

To find all exercise_templates where the workouts key match :

```
Firebase ref = yourRoot/workouts/KBIYJv6x1YU98eLIwoC/templates
```

you can find documentation here : (https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/structuring-data.html)

Comment: Thank you, I was confused by what the docs actually meant before, but after reading your post it became clear.